# PrimeFaces 7.0 <p:textEditor HTML-sanitizer discards text formatting, such as centering

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, quill, html-sanitizing

In PrimeFaces 8, it seems to be possible to enable / disable HMTML -sanitizer when using the `<p:textEditor` component by just specifying `secure='false'` for disabling it and `secure='true'` for enabling it. I tried to disable it in PrimeFaces 7.0 like this:

```
  <p:textEditor id="quillToolbarId" secure='false' widgetVar="editor2" height="300" value="#{editTemplatesBean.kaufAnbotTemplate}" placeholder="Enter your content">
```

but the sanitizer still seems to be working.

My problem is that whenever I format a text in the primeFaces p:textEditor to be center-aligned, the HTML sanitizer just removes my formatting, so the text ends up without formatting.

One way to work this around is to  use directly Quill and not Sanitize the input.This works, but then I face other problems, such as this one:

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1379

which also need to be worked-around.

Please help!

Comment: As to your issue with removing the formatting on the centered text I believe your issue is this one which is fixed for 9.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5756

Comment: @Melloware could I easily migrate to PF 8 right now? I am using Sapphire Template and have this issue when trying to migrate: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=106&t=62261

Comment: Can't you make 'Sanitizer issues' more specific in the question title?

Comment: Answered you in the forum.  PF went through and updated all the Premium templates for PF8 so go into your PrimeStore again and download the latest Saphire it should be updated for 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no secure property in TextEditor for PrimeFaces 7. If you look at the code of TextEditorRenderer.decode you will see that the sanitzier is called

```
if (PrimeApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance(context).getEnvironment().isHtmlSanitizerAvailable()) {
    value = HtmlSanitizer.sanitizeHtml(value,
          editor.isAllowBlocks(), editor.isAllowFormatting(),
          editor.isAllowLinks(), editor.isAllowStyles(), editor.isAllowImages());
}
```

And if you look into PrimeEnvironment you'll see that the property will be set if the class `org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory` is available on classpath:

```
htmlSanitizerAvailable = LangUtils.tryToLoadClassForName("org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory") != null
```

So you either:

- update to PF 8
- make sure that you don't have this class on the classpath
- override the renderer and change/remove the code for the check