# p:textEditor discards text aligning (versions 8)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, quill

This problem might be related to the one I  described earlier here:

[PrimeFaces 7.0 <p:textEditor HTML-sanitizer discards text formatting, such as centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171340/primefaces-7-0-ptexteditor-html-sanitizer-discards-text-formatting-such-as-ce)

but at least trying to switch off the HTML sanitizer in PrimeFaces 8 did not do the trick, the problem is still there. To reproduce it:

1.) Take the example from the PrimeFaces showcase, as it is shown here:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml

In case you use PrimeFaces 8.0, just augment the line

```
<p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1"  value="#{editorViewTest.text}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>
```

by the attribute `secure="false"` as follows:

```
<p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" secure="false" value="#{editorViewTest.text}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>
```

Write just a single word, i.e. Header and format it by both aligning it centrally and make it a large text. Click on the "Submit" button. The text that comes in the setter() method of the backing bean IS NOT CENTERED, but is only large.

To demonstrate:
1.) This is how the text is formatted in the editor:
[image]

2.) This is what I recieve in the debugger:
[image]

For comparison, this is my facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      lang="en">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        </f:facet>
        <title>Heimdi</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
     <h:form>    
        <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor1" secure="false" value="#{editorViewTest.text}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Submit"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and this is the backing bean:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("editorViewTest")
@RequestScoped
public class EditorView {

    private String text;

    private String text2;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return text2;
    }

    public void setText2(String text2) {
        this.text2 = text2;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kukeltje please free to take the example from the PrimeFaces show case. My example here uses the PrimeFaces templates I use

Comment: @Kukeltje  I tested with much more simpler facelet and updated my question. Seems as PrimeFaces have managed to internally work-around  a major drawback of Quill : https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1379 however, my question above might be a n example of when this work-around does not work

Comment: Good investigation (I did remove my downvote and made some additional changes to your question) If you suspect this problem/workaround, the source of PF is open. You can set breakpoints in javascript or java code and see what happens.

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you, but I tested once again IN A SEPARATE Eclipse_maven Project with its own pom.xml and its own project and.own   war filename and there .. PrimeFaces 7 works. So, the problem appears only to concern PrimeFaces 8. Sorry for my stupid tests before, but creating a new project and donwgrading my PrimeFaces sapphire files takes me a lot of time, Sorry. I've no Idea why just replacing the PrimeFaces version in my original pom.xml from 8 back to 7 did "lie" to me that I was NOT referring the HTML-sanitizer.,

Comment: Maybe the code you were running was not the code you thought you were running. Dirty deployment. You at least tried the tests, thanks for that, many others are just lazy, not you so please don't feel stupid.

Comment: And did you check what the client sent? Is it wrong already on form submission? Does it strip off each initial makeup (e.g. if it is bold instead of center? or color? or?

Comment: @Kukeltje No, i did not, must check it later

Comment: @AlexMi  I think your issue is this fixed for 9.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5756 The Sanitizer is removing paragraph p tags which are needed for alignment.

Comment: @Melloware are you sure this is a sanitizer issue? Maybe I was not able to switch it off, but why? And when would PrimeFaces 9 be available?

Comment: Oh if you have switched the Sanitizer OFF then this might be a different issue.  I would keep investigating and see if you can narrow the problem down.

Comment: @Melloware thanks for helping, I do not have more time to investigate and downgraded to PrimeFaces 7. Here it works.